# Helping to manage my amazon ec2 servers on my ipad

Tags: ipad, applications, aws

I am looking for apps that would help me to manage my amazon EC2 servers on an iPad. Are there any apps like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [Cloud Services Manager](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cloud-services-manager/id314316466?mt=8) to monitor and control my EC2, EBS and S3 instances and storage. Works okay. I wouldn't say it was wonderful, but it'll do in a pinch. If you're used to Elastic Fox you may find it a bit disappointing. Not quite as nice as EF.

More often than not I just use [Panic's Prompt ssh client for iOS](http://panic.com/prompt/support.html). It's quite good as ssh clients go and I'll use it to gain access to a known-good instance from which I can then run my own [boto](http://code.google.com/p/boto/)-enabled inspection tools or any of the standard EC2 command line utilities.

Between those two I can usually handle most of my EC2 issues from an iOS device.

Comment: thanks for the answer. What do you mean by known good instance? How do you make one? Do you use a fixed ip?

Comment: @gyurisc by known-good instance I mean an instance I know is up and running, one I know the public IP for. I have long-running instances in EC2 I can use for ssh access from iOS devices in a pinch. Some of them have fixed IPs. Some I just wrote the hostname down for.